# Changing control points while node following the path

Tags: objective-c, path, sprite-kit, curve, skaction

I have a path with starting point at the top of the screen and ending point at bottom of the screen. Also there are control points created with CGPathAddCurveToPoint:

```
        //Path

        cgpath = CGPathCreateMutable();


        float xStart    = 300.0;
        float xEnd      = 400.0;

        //ControlPoint1
        float cp1X      = 335.0;
        float cp1Y      = 465.0;

        //ControlPoint2
        float cp2X      = 320.0;
        float cp2Y      = 40.0;

        CGPoint end     = CGPointMake(xEnd, -150.0);
        CGPoint cp1     = CGPointMake(cp1X, cp1Y);
        CGPoint cp2     = CGPointMake(cp2X, cp2Y);
        CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath,NULL, xStart, self.scene.size.height);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, end.x, end.y);

        //Make path visible
        SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:cgpath];
        [line setStrokeColor:[SKColor redColor]];
        [line setLineWidth:3.8];
        [self addChild:line];
```

And there is a SKShapeNode used to make path visible(is there some other better way for this?). Moving node along the path is done by SKAction and it's done like this:

```
 SKAction *moveAlongThePath = [SKAction followPath:cgpath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];
```

Now I am trying to find a way to change values of control points (as well as starting and ending points) over time, but without interrupting SKAction. This means that node which following the path should keep following it even the end point is moved. Is this possible somehow ? Maybe using update method(which is probably not so performant way), or using another action ?

Comment: You use a `SKShapeNode` to make path visible and you ask: (is there some other better way for this?)
Yes, there is another way to do this (I don't know, if it is better): `CAShapeLayer`. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/61289/how-to-make-a-line-drawing-game-with-sprite-kit